# How to find alternative way to using max withing calculate in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to create the following measure but it fails.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Data[Total]),Data[Total]>0, Max(Period=Max Calculated Period).
```

DAX complained with the following error message:

> "A function 'MAX' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed."

I am trying to filter the result to the maximum period selected in a slicer. Please advise.

Comment: can you not do this in the SQL layer?

Comment: Sadly, No i need it as a measure.

Comment: link your slicer to a parameter in SQL?

Comment: Can't do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into similar situations. What seems to work is to put the `Max Calculated Period` into a variable in the measure and make a couple other tweaks to the definition.

Some assumptions I am making:

- `Max Calculated Period` is a measure defined within Power BI
- `Period` is a column in you `Data` table

If either of those are incorrect, this solution will not work and I would encourage you to update your question with more information and a data sample.

What that would look like is:

```
    Measure = 
    VAR MaxPeriod = [Max Calculated Period]
    RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTA(Data[Total]),
            Data[Total] > 0,
            Data[Period] = MaxPeriod
    )
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Thank you for your answer, It sound logic what function you created. However i am not bale to find return in Power BI. This is what i want to do but in Power BI user interface i am not able to return is not available. What do you recommend?

Comment: The `RETURN` keyword is just an indicator that everything before it is variables and everything after it defines the value of the measure.